# Font Family in vf page rendered as pdf

Tags: apex, visualforce, pdf, font

I have a VF page that is rendered as pdf, on that page I'm using **Helvetica** as the font family. Unfortunately, in the pdf, it's not working, and rendering all the fonts renders as Times font.

Helvetica is mentioned as a supported font family in pdf rendering [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_output_pdf_supported_fonts.htm) but one line is also written

> Text styled with any value besides those listed above receives the
> default font style, Times. This means that, ironically, while
> Helvetica's synonyms render as Helvetica, using "Helvetica" for the
> font-family style renders as Times. We recommend using "sans-serif".

I have a very poor understanding of fonts and it's families. So if anyone can explain to me what that means and what I can do to render fonts as Helvetica, would be really helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `sans-serif`, as in:

```
<style>
  body { font-family: sans-serif; }
</style>
```